# how to delete "this is the initial page of webdriver server." from selenium webdriver 2.5.0

Tags: java, selenium, jar

I m using selenium-java 2.5.0 in my application. Whenever the browser in invoked i get this message before redirecting to my seturl. "This is the initial page of webdriver server." After some research i found this line residing in iedriver.dll file on seleniu-java 2.5.0 jar.Then i delete this line from that file and build new selenium-java jar and add to my classpath.Then i get Unable to load IEDriver exception in the code.

The Exception thrown is

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'IEDriver': The specified module could not be found.
```

Then I extract the selenium jar which I recently built,but there is the `iedriver.dll` file present inside selenium jar file.

Any help please

Comment: Why you want to remove the default page? any specific reason? I don't think you/your script should have problem with it

Comment: i just want to get rid of that message.The default page with blank message is acceptable.tell me how can i delete that message

Comment: i have used desiredcapabilities "initialbrowseurl" but its not working too

Comment: Selenium 2.5.0 is **exceptionally** old. What happens if you use a more modern version, like say 2.41.0?

Comment: Also, if you're not running at least Java 6, you'll likely be out of luck.

Comment: ok thanks i will use java 6 and selenium 2.41